# How to get reference to a View inside CardView from an activity?

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I have got CardView with Views inside a RecyclerView. I have created adapter in which assets are attached to Views and everything works. Now, I would like to change these Views from my activity. Is it any simple way to do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private List<Offer>offers;
    TextView timer; //timer inside CardView

    private void getViewReferences() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
        timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getViewReferences();
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        timer.setText("13:16"); //NullPointerException here

    }
    private void initializeData(){
        offers = new ArrayList<>();
        offers.add(new Offer("godzina", R.drawable.zdj, 200));
        offers.add(new Offer("godzina", R.drawable.zdj));

    }
    private void initializeAdapter() {
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(offers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what change the views means?

Comment: @masp in initializeData()  default string "godzina" is initialized and in initializeAdapter() i am sending it to Adapter where TextView gets this value. After this operation I would like to change the text in TextView from Activity. For example : "godzina" -> "string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't want to change the Views but you want to update the text values of the views in your list.

You can't directly do that by trying to find the Views in the recyclerView and change the text. The adapter is responsible for giving values to your list. So you need to update the dataset in the adapter and call one of the [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) methods on the adapter to update the recyclerView.

The big advantage of this design is that it places Views in Cache in order to reuse them multiple times without having to inflate and construct them again. This is a huge performance improvement.

You need to read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and some tutorials to understand the adapter design pattern better.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about.Thank you for help.